# MVC3 LOGIN: create a login page and user authentication

Tags: authentication, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

i already have UserController that can create, update and delete user and it is also connected to the database using sql server 2008 .

my question is how do i **create a log-in page**  and at the same time **check if the** username and password you type is existing on my database and if not redirect to the same page.

hope you could help me i'm a beginner.

much thanks

Answer (score 0):

This question is super broad but overall the process is not really that complicated.

If you already have a controller that can perform the create, update and delete you are 90% of the way there.  All you need is code that fetches the user and checks the password they entered against the password stored in the database.

So your login page would have a form that takes a username and a passowrd.  I assume you have a create user form?  The login form could be somewhat similar.  Instead of INSERTING the username and password you just grab the row for the USERNAME and then check the passwords.  If they match, great!  If not, just return the same view.  Post some code so we can give specific examples.